# How to open correct sublist in dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-lists

I got a small Javascript menu problem.

I got a ul list that looks something like this.

```
<ul class="mainmenu">
  <li class="sub-handle">
    Item 1
    <ul class="submenu">
      <li class="sub-li">item 1-1</li>
      <li class="sub-li">item 1-2</li>
      <li class="sub-li">item 1-1</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="sub-handle">
    Item 2
    <ul class="submenu">
      <li class="sub-li">item 2-1</li>
      <li class="sub-li">item 2-2</li>
      <li class="sub-li">item 2-1</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
  <li>Item 4</li>
</ul>
```

I got php to add submenu-i++ and that works just fine. Now I have a Javascript drop down function that looks like this.

```
var sub_handle = $('.sub-handle');
var sub_nav_ul = $('nav .submenu');
var sub_nav_ul_li = $('nav .mainmenu .sub-li');
$(sub_handle).on('click', function(){
    sub_nav_ul.toggleClass('showing-sub');
    sub_nav_ul_li.toggleClass('smooth-anchor');
});
    sub_nav_ul_li.on('click', function(){
    sub_nav_ul.toggleClass('showing-sub');
});
```

The problem is that when I press any submenu all of my submenus open. I want Javascript somehow to count like php and see if submenu-i++ is pressed only that one expand.

I hope this is clear enough otherwise make a shout and I will try to explain futher.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use `$(this).find()` to get the elements within the the clicked `ul`.

Comment: None of the classes you mention in your Javascript are in the HTML. Could you make the example clearer?

Comment: Maybe what you want is `$(this).index()` to get the position of the element you clicked on in the NAV menu? Then you can use that to find the corresponding `ul`.

Comment: Thanks for quick answer! I'm really new to javascript but would I use it like this? $(this).find().on('click', function(){

Comment: Looks like you're also toggling the class on all elements since `sub_handle` is probably returning an array of elements rather than one.

Comment: Yes @Veo, that's the exact issue in a way better explanation.

Comment: @Barmar corrected the classes, my bad! :)

Comment: I still don't see `class="sub-handle"`. I see `sub-handle-1` and `sub-handle-2`.

Comment: Sorry, looked at wrong part of my code. Got it all in a php file that I haven't cleaned up yet since I'm still working on this issue. :)

Comment: Can also add I add the submenu-i++ part in php since I thought maybe you could do an equal-ish thing in javascript that could recognize the number in the class and open that exact submenu. But like I mentioned I'm new to javascript and maybe that's just plain stupid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get rid of the numbers in the classes, so all the sub-menus have ths same class. Then use DOM navigation methods to find the corresponding menu items to toggle.

```js
var sub_handle = $('.sub-handle');
var sub_nav_ul_li = $('nav .mainmenu .sub-li');
sub_handle.on('click', function() {
  $(this).find(".submenu").toggleClass('showing-sub');
  $(this).find(".sub-li").toggleClass("smooth-anchor");
});
sub_nav_ul_li.on('click', function() {
  $(this).parent().toggleClass('showing-sub');
});
```

```css
.submenu {
  display: none;
}
.submenu.showing-sub {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="mainmenu">
  <li class="sub-handle">
    Item 1
    <ul class="submenu">
      <li class="sub-li">item 1-1</li>
      <li class="sub-li">item 1-2</li>
      <li class="sub-li">item 1-1</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="sub-handle">
    Item 2
    <ul class="submenu">
      <li class="sub-li">item 2-1</li>
      <li class="sub-li">item 2-2</li>
      <li class="sub-li">item 2-1</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
  <li>Item 4</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Works like a charm, big thanks! Could you maybe add a slide function to this tho?

Comment: I guess you could put a transition in the CSS, that's a little outside my expertise.

Comment: You could also use `slideToggle` instead of changing the class.

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul class="mainmenu">
  <li class="sub-handle sub-handle-1">
    Item 1
    <ul class="submenu">
      <li class="sub-li">item 1-1</li>
      <li class="sub-li">item 1-2</li>
      <li class="sub-li">item 1-1</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="sub-handle sub-handle-2">
    Item 2
    <ul class="submenu">
      <li class="sub-li">item 2-1</li>
      <li class="sub-li">item 2-2</li>
      <li class="sub-li">item 2-1</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
  <li>Item 4</li>
</ul>

var sub_handle = $('.sub-handle');
var sub_nav_ul = $('nav .submenu');
var sub_nav_ul_li = $('.submenu .sub-li');
sub_handle.on('click', function(){
    sub_handle.removeClass("showing-sub");
    $(this).addClass('showing-sub');
    sub_nav_ul_li.toggleClass('smooth-anchor');
});
sub_nav_ul_li.on('click', function(){
    $(this).parent().removeClass('showing-sub');
});
```

Will [something like this](http://jsfiddle.net/sh3cuee7/) work:

Note: I had to edit some of the html.

Answer (score 0):

You are toggling the class on all the subitems. What you should do is traverse from the clicked handle to get the corresponding subitems for that. Something like this would suffice:

```
$(sub_handle).on('click', function(){
    $(this).find(sub_nav_ul).toggleClass('showing-sub');
    $(this).find(sub_nav_ul_li).toggleClass('smooth-anchor');
});
    sub_nav_ul_li.on('click', function(){
    $(this).closest(sub_nav_ul).toggleClass('showing-sub');
});
```

This is in no way the best solution to this, but it should help.